# ADB shell change camera mode

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-8.0-oreo

I am playing around with the ADB shell to control a Samsung Galaxy S9 remotely. I can do most of the things I wanted to but I struggle finding a way to switch / toggle the camera modes.

I searched everywhere and found very little information about this. I only found how to switch between front or back facing camera but I want to be able to select my slow motion mode.

Maybe I am not looking at the right place...

Does anyone have an idea how could I do this?

Any help is very much appreciated

thank you

Comment: [Vysor](https://www.vysor.io) this maybe related

Comment: Vysor is just another mirroring application not really what I'm looking for... But thanks for the reply